# The method getConnection(String, String, String) is undefined for the type DriverManager

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is my piece of code--

```
String userName = "username";
String password = "password";
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://WEBDBSRV/DEVPORTAL;test";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

I am trying to connect my database in one of my java product but getting following error

> The method getConnection(String, String, String) is undefined for the
>   type DriverManager.

Comment: Have you imported the correct `DriverManager` class?

Comment: Check the `DriverManager` api.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you did not encounter ClassNotFound exception means that DriverManager is in your classpath. The problem might be one of these things:

- wrong DriverManger imported
- DriverManager class version used during deployment different than used during development
- Some clash between two classes called DriverManger and loaded by different class loaders

Get your jar which contains DriverManager. Unpack it and decompile to see the signatures of methods. The fact that you managed to compile the project means that the version you are using during compilation is probably not the one used during deployment.

Comment: I have checked these but not getting anything wrong-
Here is my full code-
package testpackage;
import java.sql.*;
public class testclass {

public class ConnectDatabase {
Connection dbConnection = null;
String dbName = "silkopenview";
String userName = "SilkTestAdmin"; 
String password = "Nbv12345";
public Connection getConnection() {
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName,userName,password);
return dbConnection;
}
}
}